# Stopping auto page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use the below code to auto refresh the page every 60 seconds via the AJAX tools in VS2010.  Works perfectly.

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
  <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
         ASP.NET/HTML Code
             <p>
             <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Click here" OnClick="Button2_Click" /> to disable the pages automatic refresh.</p>
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
      </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="60000">
    </asp:Timer>
  </asp:View>
  <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
  etc.
</asp:MultiView>
```

I want to include a button on the asp.net page to cancel the auto refresh.

I tried to include the below but when I clicked the button, it didn't work.  The below is the Code Behind for an OnClick event for a Button.  The asp.net code is in the above code.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Timer1.Interval = 0;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?  Is this even a way to do this or do I need to go another route in order to allow the user to cancel the auto page refresh?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on this and just going off the top of my head but wouldn't it be Timer1.Enabled = false;

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of disabling it.  I was just working under the assumption that setting it to 0 might do it.  Jeez, that was a bit of a dumb assumption.  lol  I'll change that and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [PeterJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599751/peterj) I have found the solution.  I modified the code and since I clicked it the page has not refreshed.  The issue was with my code behind for the button OnClick event.  I had:

```
Timer1.Interval = 0;
```

When I should have had:

```
Timer1.Enabled = false;
```